# Retrieve Person object from Redis without providing hashcode

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redis, spring-data-redis

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am inserting a Person object in Redis. Now When inserting the object, I also need to provide the hashCode value for Person retrieved. Is there any way, I can retrieve the Person object without passing the hashCode, just the key part. Kindly let me know. Here is the insert code :

Insert code :

```
Person person = // person retrieved from DB.
this.userAppRegistration.getRedisTemplate().opsForHash().put(String.valueOf(person.getId()),person.hashCode(),person);
```

Retrieval code :

```
this.userAppRegistration.getRedisTemplate().opsForHash().get("Key_Available",)
```

I don't have access to hashcode of the Person I inserted at this point. How can I still retrieve the Person object using only key. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a key-value store. You put there a value with a key, and you retrieve it with the same key.

You've decided to make your key a combination of person's ID, hashcode and the person itself (or rather its `toString()` most likely). Don't do that. It makes no sense whatsoever, and as you're now noticing it makes it impossible for you to retrieve the value.

Comment: How shall I insert and retrieve then? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Something that you can use later on, such as a person's ID or username or whatever. Depends on your business rules. Ask your Borg brothers.

Comment: Thanks, and my Borg bro's have replied. This works : http://pastebin.com/MZG9rgkR . Can you tell me if this is a correct approach? Thanks a lot. Cant ask my borg brothers, they are regenerating. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Now that looks a lot smarter.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. :-) I return to my my alcove. Bye. :-)